# Replace sequence of spaces in string with a single character in swift

Tags: string, swift, replace

I want to replace a series of spaces from a string with an underscore. For example

```
"This       is     a string with a lot of spaces!"
```

should become

```
"This_is_a_string_with_a_lot_of_spaces!"
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Alternative non-regex solution:

```
let foo = "This       is     a string with a lot of spaces!"
let bar = foo
    .componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
    .filter { !$0.isEmpty }
    .joinWithSeparator("_")

print(bar) /* This_is_a_string_with_a_lot_of_spaces! */
```

Works also for unicode characters (thanks @MartinR for this beautiful example)

```
let foo = "       "

// ...

/* _____ */
```

Comment: That's a pretty slick use of Filter.

Comment: @NateBirkholz I should point out, however, that this method above will not replace groups of spaces prior and after the first and last words, respectively; these spaces will just be removed (e.g. `"   This       is     a string with a lot of spaces!   "` will yield the same result as for `"This       is     a string with a lot of spaces!"`).

Comment: That is exactly what I need, so that won't be a problem

Answer (score 6):

@remus suggestion can be simplified (and made Unicode/Emoji/Flag-safe) as

```
let myString = "  This       is     a string with a lot of spaces!         "
let replacement = myString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\s+", withString: "_", options: .RegularExpressionSearch)
print(replacement)
// _This_is_a_string_with_a_lot_of_spaces!____
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple regular expression replacement to do this:

```
let myString = "     "
if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\s+", options: []) {
    let replacement = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(myString, options: .WithTransparentBounds, range: NSMakeRange(0, (myString as NSString).length), withTemplate: "_")
    print(replacement)
    // "_____"
}
```

Comment: Test your code with the `let myString = "            "` ... :)

Comment: WHHHYYYYY UNICODE WHYYYY

Answer (score 1):

Alternative non-regex, pure Swift (no bridging to `NSString`) solution:

```
let spaced = "This       is     a string with a lot of spaces!"

let under = spaced.characters.split(" ", allowEmptySlices: false).map(String.init).joinWithSeparator("_")
```

Alternate, alternate version that doesn't remove leading and trailing spaces when converting. Slightly obfuscated for brevity... ;-)

```
let reduced = String(spaced.characters.reduce([Character]()) { let n = $1 == " " ? "_" : $1; var o = $0; o.append(n); guard let e = $0.last else { return o }; return e == "_" && n == "_" ? $0 : o })
```

There's probably a more clever solution involving `flatMap()` but I'll leave it to someone more clever than I!

Comment: Just note that as in @dfris' solution, this will remove and not replace initial and trailing spaces.